# Parse.com - Adding <user>Pointer __User & ACL

Tags: parse-platform

I am attempting to add a row to a Class in my Parse database using the API

I have managed to get the row added but I noticed that both the 'ACL & user__user' fields are blank.

My Request class looks like this:

```
public class AccountDataRequest
    {
        public string OrderNo { get; set; }
        public string SiteName { get; set; }
        public string CreditDebit { get; set; }
        public int Amount { get; set; }
        public int CreditBalance { get; set; }
    }
```

And my function looks like this:

```
public static AccountDataResponse AddTransaction(AccountDataRequest details)
    {
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.parse.com/1/classes/AccountData");
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("X-Parse-Application-Id", "xxxxx");
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", "xxxxx");

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(details);

            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();

            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AccountDataResponse>(result);
            }
        }
    }
```

The 'user__user' links to the 'objectID(String)' in mu Users class.

I have tried adding it to my class as a string but it throws and error.

Can anyone tell me how to get the ACL and 'user__user' populated please?

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

I have learnt that the Pointer is a structure so have amended my classes as follows:

```
public class AccountDataRequest
{
    public string OrderNo { get; set; }
    public string SiteName { get; set; }
    public string CreditDebit { get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; }
    public int CreditBalance { get; set; }
    public Pointer Pointer { get; set; }
}

public class Pointer
{
    public string __type { get; set; }
    public string className { get; set; }
    public string objectId { get; set; }
}
```

So, when I now call the API with the following:

```
POST https://api.parse.com/1/classes/AccountData HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
X-Parse-Application-Id: xxxxx
X-Parse-REST-API-Key: xxxxx
Host: api.parse.com
Content-Length: 163
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

{"OrderNo":"9","SiteName":"Trev","CreditDebit":"Debit","Amount":1.0,"CreditBalance":999,"Pointer":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"AccountData","objectId":"fvJ8jPjyjx"}}
```

This call produces no errors and returns a createddate and an objectid but the user(Pointer <__User> is still null.

I also tried changing the className to "__User" to which the API responds:

```
{"code":111,"error":"invalid type for key Pointer, expected *AccountData, but got *_User"}
```

This is what the empty column looks like in my AccountData class

[image]

And I am trying to tie it to the objectId in my User table:

[image]

Can anyone see what is wrong please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the column in Parse is defined as a Pointer to _User, then you need to pass the appropriate structure to Parse and not just the objectId. Take a look at the [Data Types section](https://www.parse.com/docs/rest#objects-types) of the Parse REST SDK. It has a paragraph and sample for passing a Pointer structure through the API.

Similarly, for ACLs you need to specify that structure as well. Details for it are in the [security docs](https://www.parse.com/docs/rest#roles-security) for the SDK.

In both cases, if you want to use an object->JSON converter, you'll need to build an object that appropriately represents that structure. That'll be a bit easier for Pointers than ACLs as the former has predefined keys whereas the latter uses dynamic key names (e.g. objectIds and role names).

**Updated to include class definition**

```
public class AccountDataRequest
{
    public string OrderNo { get; set; }
    public string SiteName { get; set; }
    public string CreditDebit { get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; }
    public int CreditBalance { get; set; }
    public Pointer user { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question with your help but still not got it working - are you able to take another look please?

Comment: The field name in your class needs to match the field name in Parse. So if the field in parse is "user__user", you'd need to include that in your class. Updated my answer to illustrate.

Comment: Lol - I have now tried user_user, User_user, user_User and again, no errors from the API but my link columns is still blank. I have added some images to my question - what would you think the pointer should be called?

Comment: Just user. The resulting JSON for that field should be "user": {"__type": "Pointer", "className": "_User", "objectId": "fvJ8jPjyjx"}

Comment: I know I am not supposed to do +1 & thanks. but thanks! I don't think I could have found that without you.

Comment: @RyanDuffy  can u kindly tell me i  getting same issue how to save ppointer of User table in installation table using parse.com in android
in installation table there is this snapshot imgur.com/lShguu5 a pointer of User table i.e objectiD OF user where as object id of user i m getting at the time of sign up of user see this imgur.com/6P7ggQs 
now i m failed to save pointer user in installation table

Comment: @TrevorDaniel how to save ppointer of User table in installation table using parse.com in android
in installation table there is this snapshot imgur.com/lShguu5 a pointer of User table i.e objectiD OF user where as object id of user i m getting at the time of sign up of user see this imgur.com/6P7ggQs 
now i m failed to save pointer user in installation table